# XML Master/detail data selection when master and detail are separate dataset inside the XML

Tags: xml, xpath, master-detail, msxml, selectnodes

Please assume the following actual XML structure (no, we cannot change it).

```
<root>
  <master>
    <record>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Value>One</Value>
    </record>
    <record>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Value>Two</Value>
    </record>
  </master>
  <detail>
    <record>
      <ID>A</ID>
      <MasterID>1</MasterID>
      <Value>Somevalue a</Value>
    </record>
    <record>
      <ID>B</ID>
      <MasterID>2</MasterID>
      <Value>Somevalue b</Value>
    </record>
    <record>
      <ID>C</ID>
      <MasterID>1</MasterID>
      <Value>Somevalue c</Value>
    </record>
    <record>
      <ID>D</ID>
      <Value>Somevalue d</Value>
    </record>
  </detail>
</root>
```

First we perform an XPath query on the XML to return a list of possible detail records:

```
detailnodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('/root/detail')
```

Then we handle each returned detailrecord in the return XML nodelist, at which point we need the value of the master record based on the MasterID in the detailnode using an XPath expression only.
We don't want to use application code to retreive the MasterID of the current record and then create an XPath expression based on the retreived value

Example (not like this)

```
for each detailnode in detailnodes do
  masterID = detailnode.ChildNodes['MasterID'].value
  masterValue = detailnode.selectNodes('../master[ID=" + MasterID + "]/Value')[0].value
end
```

Example (preferred way)

```
for each detailnode in detailnodes do
  masterValue = detailnode.selectNodes('../master[ID=?MasterID?]/Value')[0].value
end
```

The `?MasterID?` expression inside the XPath should return the MasterID value of the current detailnode.

Is this even possible using pure XPath expressions...?

**EDIT**
Note: I need to get this working using the MSXML DOM...

Comment: I just see, that you write the `value` with a small `v`. But your XML has it capitalized. This might be a hard to find "error"

Comment: OK, I'll update the demo (the actual structure is much more complex, this was only to explain the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to do this using MSXML, so I'll need the try something else to make the X-Path more dynamic, without needing to modify code for specific XML-structures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to lookup values elsewhere in the Xml Document, keyed by data in the current scope, by using [`current()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/current). Also, note that Xml indexing is 1 based, so you'll need to use `[1]`, like so:

```
(//master/record[ID=current()/MasterID]/Value)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it seems msxml DOM does not support the `current()` function.
- added this requirement to the initial question

Comment: You're right - it seems nigh impossible to get an XSL context into play with MSXml DOM. With XPath 3, the [`let` keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-let-expressions) allows capture of external state (But MS support only a V1 Processor). Alternatively, you might consider doing the xml transformation in XSLT? That does allow for `current()`

Comment: Thanks for your idea - but for now it seems not solvable using X-Path only. And at this time XSLT is not directly useable for me, as I don't know how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

An `XQuery` like this

```
for $r in /root/detail/record 
  return <record>
         {
           <MasterValue>
           {
             /root/master/record[(ID/text())[1]=($r/MasterID/text())[1]]/Value/text()
           }
           </MasterValue> 
           | $r/*
           }
        </record>
```

Will return

```
<record>
   <ID>A</ID>
   <MasterID>1</MasterID>
   <Value>Somevalue a</Value>
   <MasterValue>One</MasterValue>
</record>
<record>
   <ID>B</ID>
   <MasterID>2</MasterID>
   <Value>Somevalue b</Value>
   <MasterValue>Two</MasterValue>
</record>
<record>
   <ID>C</ID>
   <MasterID>1</MasterID>
   <Value>Somevalue c</Value>
   <MasterValue>One</MasterValue>
</record>
<record>
   <ID>D</ID>
   <Value>Somevalue d</Value>
   <MasterValue/>
</record>
```

Comment: Is this possible using MSXML DOM with the `SelectNodes` routine of an XML node? (see added requirement)...

Comment: @R.Hoek Sorry, I don't know by experience how `SelectNodes` works... But the way I use to find the corresponding value **within** the `XPath` should work. Do not ask the nodes on `<master>` level, but iterate through the records in `<detail>` and find the corresponding master value with an expression like `//master/record[ID=./MasterID]/Value`. The dot in `./MasterID` points to the current element. If you add the `/text()` or not is more a matter of taste (in your case).

Comment: basicly I'm itterating over the detail nodes:
```detailnodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('/root/detail')
for each detailnode in detailnodes do```

And I tried the ```./MasterID``` but that does not function too. Looking at the reply bij @StuartLC I'm expecting this won't work with MSXML (at this time).

Comment: @R.Hoek Your example shows `.selectNodes('../master[ID=" + MasterID + "]/Value')[0]`. Did this work, at least for the `../master`? If the `..` are supported, the `.` should be supported too, but I cannot test this here...

Comment: '@Shnugo: the 'not wanted situation' example works (this is how things work now). But I would like to do the same, without coding, using a pure X-Path expression. The ```./``` works only in the context of the node that's evaluated for filtering. And as the ```master``` records do not have a ```MasterID``` node, the result is nothing.